# calculate the prize of a game of chance! (makes no sense to me)

Tags: probability

> A bag contains $12$ yellow and $8$ purple marbles. Joe pays $\$2$ for the opportunity to pick a marble from the bag. If he picks a yellow marble, he does not get anything. If he picks a purple marble, he gets $k.$ The game is fair. Find the value of $k.$

I honestly don't get the correlation between the prize and the rest of the question. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: sorry, i dont know why the font is so weird but i couldnt manage to fix it.

Comment: We use dollar signs to set off MathJax.  If you want a dollar sign you need to escape it with a backslash.  Otherwise, don't specify the currency, as it does not change the problem.  What is the chance he picks a yellow marble?  What is his expected return for playing the game?  We are told the game is fair, so this must be $2$.  That lets you find $k$

Comment: Let's say the prize were $\$1000$. You would be very motivated to play this game. If the prize were $\$0$, you would not want to play, since you'd be losing $\$2$ every time without ever winning anything back. Somewhere between those extremes, there's a value where everyone's happy (both you and the person hosting the game).

Comment: As far as I know *fair game* is the game where *total cost* equals to *expected gain*

Comment: If the game is fair the expected value is zero.  That is, the probability of winning times the size of the prize equals the cost to enter.

Comment: The odds are $3:2$ against winning so a fair game should pay $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the game is fair means that the expected gain of Joe is $0$. If it was positive then it would have been unfair to the game maker, if it was negative it would been unfair to Joe. Now, Joe wins $k-2$ if he picks a purple marble, otherwise he wins $-2$(or loses $2$). So,

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[gain\ of\ Joe] &= \mathbb P[Joe\ picks\ purple] \cdot (k-2) + \mathbb P[Joe\ picks\ yellow] \cdot (-2) \\\implies \mathbb E[gain\ of\ Joe] &= \frac{8}{20} \cdot (k-2) + \frac{12}{20} \cdot (-2) \\\implies \mathbb E[gain\ of\ Joe] &= \frac{2(k-5)}{5}
\end{align}$$

Setting $\mathbb E[gain\ of\ Joe] = 0$ yields $k = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that you receive a yellow marble is $\frac{12}{20} = \frac35.$ The probability you receive a purple marble is $1 - \frac35 = \frac25.$ Since Joe pays $2$ dollars and he expects to win this money back once he plays this game $5$ times.

He would theoretically get nothing $3$ times and something $2$ times out of the $5$ times he plays this game. So, after spending $10$ dollars, he should break even. We know that $\frac{10}{2} = 5,$ so $k = 5.$

Comment: However, I'm assuming that fair here means that he should theoretically break even.

Comment: The odds are $3:2$